# get the max volume from an arrayList of type objects

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

ok so I made a class that implements comparable

```
 public abstract class Shape3D implements Comparable<Shape3D>
 {
private String type;
public double radious;
public double height;

public Shape3D(){

}
protected Shape3D(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}



public abstract double area();

public abstract double volume();

public int compareTo(Shape3D o) {
    double volume1 = this.volume();
    double volume2 = o.volume();
    if (volume1 > volume2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (volume1 < volume2){
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public int compareTo2(Shape3D o) {
    double area1 = this.area();
    double area2 = o.area();
    if (area1 > area2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (area1 < area2){
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}


     }
```

two classes will extend from this one Cylinder and Pyramid and I have a class that reads a file and returns an array of the file

```
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Scanner;

      public class ShapeReader {
private File inputFile;


public ShapeReader(){

}

      public ShapeReader(File inputFile){
this.inputFile = inputFile;
     }





      public ArrayList<Shape3D> readShapes(){
ArrayList<Shape3D> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape3D>();

 try {
     inputFile = new File("shapes3D.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (inputFile);



     while(sc.hasNextLine()){
         String type = sc.nextLine();
        if (type.contains("Pyramid")){
            String[] data = type.split(",");
             Pyramid p = new Pyramid();
             p.setType(data[0]);
             p.setBase(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
             p.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
             p.setSlant(Double.parseDouble(data[3]));
             shapes.add(p);

        }
         else if (type.contains("Cylinder")){
             String[] data = type.split(",");
             Cylinder c = new Cylinder();
             c.setType(data[0]);
             c.setRadious(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
             c.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
             shapes.add(c);


         }



     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

 }
 return shapes;
      }
      }
```

now on the class that has the main method I have this method

```
      public Shape3D maxVolume(ArrayList<Shape3D> shapes ){


    Shape3D currentMax;
   int currentMaxIndex = 0;  
   for ( int i = 1; i < shapes.size(); i++)  
   {  
currentMax = shapes.get(i);  
currentMaxIndex = i;  
if(currentMax.compareTo(shapes.get(i)) < 0)  
      {  
       currentMax = shapes.get(i);  
      currentMaxIndex = i;  
      }  
      }  
      return currentMaxIndex;  
}
```

but it gives me an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Shape3D how can I solve this issue, I tried to give you guys as much details as I could

Answer (score 0):

Your `maxVolume()` method has a declared return type of `Shape3D`, but you are returning `currentMaxIndex` which is an `int`.  Perhaps you meant to return `currentMax` instead?

Also, just to head off your next question, you are assigning `currentMax` and `currentMaxIndex` twice in your for loop, once before and once after your comparison.  This means you're always going to be comparing each element to itself, rather than a current maximum.

You need to set `currentMax` to some minimum value before your for loop, so that it will always compare as less than the first element.

Comment: ok I did what you did and but It still does not return anything, maybe I need to print it inside the main method, how can I do this

Comment: If you've updated your code, you should edit your question to include the updates.  Regarding printing, you want to @Override the `toString()` method and have it return a `String` which contains the object info in a human-readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the method as `public Shape3D maxVolume(ArrayList<Shape3D> shapes )` i.e. with return type of `Shape3D`. However, you are actually returning an `int` i.e. `currentMaxIndex`. That's the cause of the error.

You can change the returned value to `shapes.get(currentMaxIndex)`to fix the issue.

Comment: @shree.part18 ok I think your solution will work this is what I have now return shapes.get(currentMaxIndex); and I think I have to print it on the main method to get it to work but I don't know how since it takes parameters

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this requirement? If possible, please edit your question and add the relevant code.